# Wordpress rewrite match not returning correct value

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I have created a rule to rewrite urls `croziere/{example}/{example}` to pages named with a combernation of the contents of the last two slashes. Eg `croziere/destination/uk` to `index.php?pagename=destination-uk`.

```
 function custom_rewrite_rule() {

    add_rewrite_rule('^croaziere/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','/index.php?  page_name=$matches[1]-$matches[2]','top');

 }


 add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

here's how the htaccess looks :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /travel/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^croaziere/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/? /travel/index.php?pagename=$matches[1]-$matches[2] [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /travel/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and here is the rewrite debug :

Comment: Hi Frank, you already have a open question relating to rewrites, has that question been solved?

Comment: Hi David, I have deleted that question.

Comment: you should have just accepted if it solved that issue! you needed to provide a few sample uris for the question above.

Comment: @David is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

The correct regex is:

```
croziere/([a-z]*)/([a-z]*)
```

which for `croziere/destination/uk` will return

```
array(
   0    =>  croziere/destination/uk
   1    =>  destination
   2    =>  uk
)
```

update, if you want to combine matches into a single word....confirmed working assume you have a pagename with a structure `something-something` and the page exists. btw make sure you flush the rewrite rules rather than adding directly to htaccess, if you are you need to properly escape the appropriate characters.

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {

   add_rewrite_rule('croaziere/([a-z]*)/([a-z]*)','/index.php?pagename=$1-$2','top');

 }


 add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule');
```

Comment: Cheers David, I will up-vote you when I have the rep.

Comment: you should be able to accept the answer now, i think that gives you a bit of rep as well

Comment: updated above, it's working, the rewrite base i have not checked, its beyond the scope of what you asked!

Comment: Thanks David, that's working, but is redirecting to the page as opposed to rewriting?

Comment: its because you are serving a page rather than a file, the normal use of wp rewrite would be to serve a controller file rather than an existing page.

Comment: Is there anyway to stop index from re rewriting?

Comment: dont think so, you are going through index.php so unless you have a file that calls your page....but you are sort of paying the price for the method you are using. this would be for another question or further research, but using taxonomy terms would be a better idea in the url, e.g. uk/london would be a custom post type called city and destination would be the taxonomy. Matching to a pagename called uk-london is kinda bad design as the original uri has the information in there, google sees it, parses it, if your new uri also gets parsed, you have duplicate content.